# How to run two commands simultaneously using winexe?

Tags: linux, windows

Is it possible to run two commands using winexe, I tried below format

./winexe --authentication-file=auth //10.0.0.2 "command1 & command2"

but it just displays the help option for "command1" and ./winexe --authentication-file=auth //10.0.0.2 "command1" works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it `winexe` runs commands in Windows, not in a `cmd` shell. So what I think you need is:

```
./winexe --authentication-file=auth //10.0.0.2 'cmd /c "command1 & command2"'
```

See the [winexe wiki](https://lbtwiki.cern.ch/bin/view/Online/WinExe).

Answer (score 0):

When you run multiple commands with conditional processing symbols, the commands to the right of the conditional processing symbol act based upon the results of the command to the left of the conditional processing symbol **&**. For example, you might want to run a command only if the previous command fails. Or, you might want to run a command only if the previous command is successful.